# Python/Django: How to reactivate pipenv after exiting

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, pipenv, virtual-environment

Please Everybody. I have a little problem with pipenv. 
For instance, I am work on a Django project and I decided to sleep. I had to shutdown my laptop for some reason. Then i woke up navigated to the project and I open it in VScode again. My question is how to I reactivate the pipenv environment again.

I mean something like `source bin/activate` if you are using virtualenv

I use `pipenv shell` but i want to be sure that is absolutely right.

Answer (score 0):

`pipenv —venv` to get the location of the virtualenv

Then activate it like a normal virtualenv.

Comment: Shouldn't this be `pipenv --venv` @Suicide Bunny ?

Answer (score 0):

As a new user of both Django and Pipenv I recently ran into the same issue. Maybe this will help someone. 
(for Mac m1 steps maybe different for you)

1. expose hidden folders inside the home directory.
     Shift + command + > 
   you should see a folder called " .local." follow it through... 
   .local > share, virtualenvs.  The virtualenvs is what your looking for. It contains folders for all of pipenvs.
2. from the integrated terminal inside vscode I cd into whichever pipenv folder coorespondes to the project I'm working on then run: 
   source bin/activate. 
   the terminal should return with an indicator in parens ahead of user name confirming the shell is active again: 
   (**Blog**) user@user-MBP Blog %
3. cd back into project folder (the one containing manage.py)  and run
    python manage.py runserver 
   should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

`pipenv --venv` => outputs the virtual environment directory (ie "/Users/td/.local/share/virtualenvs/data-infra-HlhPgy0O")

You can copy the output of the previous command and then run (on zsh):

`source [vitrual_environment_directory]/bin/activate`

(ie `source /Users/td/.local/share/virtualenvs/data-infra-HlhPgy0O/bin/activate`)